# Please burninate the “stuck” tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

Please burninate the [stuck](/questions/tagged/stuck) tag.

It adds no value and appears to have been used haphazardly.

Comment: Should [infinite-loop] be burninated, if [stuck] is burninated?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, [infinite-loop] appears to be serving a purpose.  [Stuck] appears to be tagged randomly for a variety of meta and looping scenarios.  Perhaps a few "stuck" questions could be retagged as [infinite loop]?  A tag synonym made?  Probably better just to burninate "stuck" and not look back.

Comment: People can use [infinite-loop] to describe a particular way in which their program isn't working.  [Stuck] *could* be used to describe e.g. a deadlock by someone who doesn't know the correct terminology, but my bet is that it's used mostly by students who are [stuck] on their assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's best to both retag it, so they get their [infinite-loop](/questions/tagged/infinite-loop) tag or whichever they need; and burninate it, so it doesn't reappear in the future.

Whenever something is stuck, it is frozen or hangs. It is an important detail to the question, but the tag itself is indeed unnecessary as it does not tell what exactly has happened.

Comment: With only 30 questions (at the time of writing) this is a) sensible and b) feasible.

Comment: @ChrisF, there were over 40 "stuck" questions when I posted this question. Now there are 0 and it looks like [Mat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/) has edited every question, bless him.

Comment: I'll give Mat a few hours (I'm going offline) to post an answer, since he did all that work.  Otherwise, this looks like the answer.

Comment: @BrockAdams - I did a few too ;) But even at 40+ it was still sensible to do manually.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes, and I have retagged many dozens of posts in such efforts.  But one of the tags ("STS" IIRC) rises from the dead periodically.  That's why I was hoping for a more permanent (and probably dead-easy), SQL-based fix.   Still, I don't know why I forgot to come back after a couple of weeks and do this tag the hard way.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was hoping for a proper "burninate".  Just 3 hours ago, [someone posted a question with the offending tag](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8281941/revisions).  So, I'll subscribe to that tag and play whack-a-mole for... (^_^)