# Should the [weirdness] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta-tags

IMHO, [weirdness](/questions/tagged/weirdness) is in the same bucket as [stuck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111474/please-burninate-the-stuck-tag), [problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107853/please-blacklist-the-problem-tag-again), [not-working and error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95513/not-working-tag).

Weirdness, in the context of the tagged questions, describes unexpected behaviour/output which is often down to a lack of knowledge or misunderstanding by the OP of the technology in question. Weirdness is therefore relative, and the tag a meta-tag.

Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like sound reasoning to me.

Comment: And then someone creates a framework called "weirdness"

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Now, you are giving me an idea.

Comment: Why is this first in the new questions list? It was asked like an hour ago...

Comment: @Gabe perhaps there's some weirdness in the sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]