# Burnination candidates - [annoyance], [beauty], [fancy], [art]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-block-request, meta-tags

I would like to propose the following tags for burnination:

- [annoyance](/questions/tagged/annoyance), [annoyances](/questions/tagged/annoyances), [web-annoyances](/questions/tagged/web-annoyances): same arguments as [weirdness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116269/should-the-weirdness-tag-be-burninated), i.e. it is a result of ones expectations of how something should work. It is relative to the viewer, not specific to any technology, and therefore a meta-tag.
- [beauty](/questions/tagged/beauty) and [fancy](/questions/tagged/fancy): again, relative to the eyes of the beholder.
- [art](/questions/tagged/art) as suggested in comments.

Comment: [beauty] is orhpan now (really low volume, not sure it requires burnination), but I saw [tag:art] while cleaning up - might want to pick that one up too.

Comment: Disambiguated some of the legitimate [tag:fancy]s (those referring to projects with fancy in their name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of those tags (and also [web-annoyances](/questions/tagged/web-annoyances) and [annoyances](/questions/tagged/annoyances)) are now orphaned and will age away on their own in 24 hours.

Not sure if they've been removed and reintroduced before, though. Seems likely since they're not exactly obscure (or at least [annoyance](/questions/tagged/annoyance) isn't), so I think blacklisting would be a good next step.

Comment: Sounds sensible. Will look them up again some time in the future and see if the tags resurface. Will bump question if they do and request for blacklisting.